# Angular : how to create the row dynamically in angular

Tags: html, angular

I am using

```
<div *ngFor="let item of object | keyvalue">
      {{item.key}}:{{item.value}}
    </div>
```

to print the value in html. but I need to print it in form of table

say total we have 8 key value pair, now i want to create the new row after 4th key value pair, such that it should come in this way

```
a a a a
a a a a
```

can we do it dynamically, the key value pair can be 12 or 16, multiple of 4

Answer (score 0):

you could convert your structure into a more suitable one and use a nested loop.
This would also lead to a data structure more similar to a table.

something like that

```
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let item of arr">
      <td *ngFor="let td of item">
        {{td}}
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and in your components ts file.

```
let i = 0;
const itemsPerRow = 4;
    Object.keys(this.object).forEach((key,index) => {
      if(index > 0 && index % itemsPerRow == 0) {
        i++;
      }

      if(!this.arr[i]) {
        this.arr[i] = [];
      }

      this.arr[i].push(this.object[key]);

    });
```

this will convert your structure into an array of objects where every array item represents one row.

[Here's a working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fgqkza?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Just as further info.
You can get the index of your current element in your `*ngFor` like
  `*ngFor="let item of items;let i = index"`